# Find View id in source code from Crashlytics crash report

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I release an app with Crashlytics inside to send crash report, here is report I received:

> "Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. 
>   Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131493375, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.nhatnq.app.b.cr)]
>          at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java)
>          at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java)
>   ..."

I want to know which Apdater/ListView got this crash, so I want to trace from these things:

- "com.nhatnq.app.b.cr": package name is hidden, I can not know. In my app, I have an "ExpandableContactAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter" in package com.nhatnq.app.contact.ExpandableContactAdapter.java, and some Fragments which include adapter such as *com.nhatnq.app.fragment.HistoryFragment$ExpandableHistoryAdapter,
  com.nhatnq.app.fragment.MessageFragment$ExpandableMessageAdapter,...*
- ListView(2131493375): this is ID of ListView. I convert this from dec to hex, then find in my local source code (in R.java), but not found this resource ID. Perhaps ID is encoded by time key when release.

What I need to check here, to find correct ListView/Adapter then I can check? Now I have 5 adapters and really do not know what need to check, as this issue only happen on some phones.
I work in a team, other guy take responsible for releasing app from team source code.

Comment: Just check all adapter and find out in which one you are trying to update it inside background thread.probably in crashlytics you will get all details including class name and line as well.

Comment: No line found in crash report, that's why I can not know exactly what adapter got problem :( Because I have a root view (SlidingMenu), when this view layoutChildren(), one of adapter get crash, so no line code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your release "guy" is probably using Proguard or something similar, so the class name is obsfucated (class com.nhatnq.app.b.cr). This is a procedure makes it harder for someone to reverse engineer your code.

You need to ask him to Retrace (or deobfuscate) the code so you can properly identify the class. He should retain files for doing this, in the case of Proguard, here is a reference:

http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/android-how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-from-stack-trace/

Comment: Wow, I do not know that I can trace back from Produard mapping file, thank you. Now I can find which adapter cause my crash.